# Имеется ли в Android Studio какой-то аналог Playground как в XCode? Или же возможность быстрого запуска отдельного java файла без эмулятора?

Tags: java, android-studio

Иногда бывает делаешь какой-то метод и после каждого исправления его надо быстро протестировать, но ждать пока он запустится в эмуляторе, а потом ещё дойти до него в приложении это утомительно. В XCode имелся очень удобный инструмент Playground, в котором можно было писать код и он тут же компилировался наживую и видны были состояния всех переменных, а потом уже после отладки код можно было перенести в приложение. Я конечно понимаю что такая альтернатива вряд ли есть в студии, но может есть хотя бы возможность запустить лишь один java файл, логи которого бы выводились в консоль?

Comment: Playground никогда не пользовался. Всегда создавал отдельный проект. Да и полезно хранить исходники, что ни говорил.

Comment: Для Android Studio можно написать плагин.

Comment: Ради налаживания одной маленькой функции целый проект создавать как-то жирно) А готовые плагины есть?

Answer (score 0):

Если работать с эмулятором или устройством с API >= 20, то имеется возможно применять изменения на лету, справа вверху молния

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Знаю об этой функции, но отказался от нее давно по некоторым причинам.